# Controlling Dafny naming convention and using constants

Tags: dafny

Is there any way to control the naming convention Dafny uses for the target code?

Is it possible to use a symbolic constant globally? Something like this:

```
? global const MaxValue = 10000; ?

method Method1 (a : int) returns (b : int)
  requires a < MaxValue
```

Is there any way to convert a numeric expression to string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and yes.

To control the names of various entities that Dafny uses in the target code, use the `{:extern "ThisIsTheNameIWant"}` attribute.  This attribute is supported on most declarations.  For example, you can put one on a class and another on a method inside the class.  For more examples, see the `Test/dafny0/Extern.dfy` file in the Dafny test suite. If you want to look at what is generated, use the `/spillTargetCode:1` flag from the command line.

For constants, use:

```
const MaxValue := 10000
```

(Note, until recently, you had to supply the type of constants explicitly, so you had to write

```
const MaxValue: int := 10000
```

If you're building the latest version of Dafny from sources, the type is inferred from the right-hand side expression.)

A nifty feature, borrowed from Ada language, is that you can insert an underscore between any two digits in numeric literals. If you work with large literals with a bunch a zeros in them, then this makes it easier for your eyes to see that you have written the correct number.  For example:

```
const MaxValue := 10_000
const PhoneNumber := 512_555_1212
const SignedInt32Limit := 0x8000_0000
```

Rustan

Comment: Rustan, thank you for your most helpful answer. I'd be very grateful if you could look into my recent post 'Dafny rejects a simple postcondition', too.